# Create a pdf in Xamarin.Android using iTextSharp with a Letterhead

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, bitmap, itext, bitmapfactory

I successfully managed to create a pdf file using iTextSharp with a table inside it. I am trying to add in on top a letterhead image from inside the drawable folder

I have tried to add it using

```
iTextSharp.text.Image _image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Resource.Drawable.LetterHead);
```

But i get an error cannot convert 'int' to 'iTextSharp.text.Image'

Thank you in advance...

Comment: You can read image from the Assets folder with following code `Stream s = this.Assets.Open("LetterHead.png");  iTextSharp.text.Image _image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(s);`

Comment: Becase the `iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance` just support these input type like this thread https://imgur.com/a/D0oDGMY